# Explicitly setting the duration of a JFR event

Tags: jfr

I'm working on a Micrometer registry that sends metrics to JFR. I'm making good progress so far using `EventFactory` and `Event#set(int, Object)`. However one thing I'm struggling with at the moment is that Micrometer explicitly wants to set the duration of events, for example using `io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer#record(long, TimeUnit)`. Is there a way to set the duration of a JFR event other than by using `#start()` and `#end()`? Or do I have to introduce a new custom attribute for the duration that I can set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom attribute.

You can use @jdk.jfr.Timespan(Timespan.NANOSECOONDS) to indicate that it should be displayed as a duration.